# Intermittent Unicode issue on web pages (perl, apache, fast cgi)

Tags: apache, perl, utf-8, fastcgi

We are using perl and fastcgi on servers. The pages are l10n'ed for multiple languages.  On some but not all pages we are seeing the black diamonds of doom, but on the same page in a different language we are seeing no such issue.  It doesn't appear to be database related as we've seen the issue even when the db response is only ascii.  It also doesn't appear to happen for every user to the pages.

https://fbref.com/en/players/b56b56d7/Kevin-Le-Sauce
vs
https://fbref.com/it/calciatori/b56b56d7/Kevin-Le-Sauce

In the screenshots below the db data being used is exactly the same.

[image: Page in English]
[image: Page in Italian]

Our current best theory is that it's related to FASTCGI and Apache but we are at a loss as to why it's happening the way it is and not for all queries.

Comment: It's pretty easy: HTTP and HTML says the document is in `UTF-8` while it's actually `ISO-8859-1` (look at it in a hex editor). And given that [everything is wrongly displayed](https://abload.de/img/20210224notutf82zkoy.png) I guess one of your template/language files is wrongly encoded.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that easy.  If we run "file" on every script and template they show up as utf8 or ASCII,  the two pages use the same templates as we are using Locale::TextDomain  for i18n

Comment: You haven't shared any code, so not much to go on. Check none of your scripts are re-encoding any strings. Check output handles are set to utf8. Check your database connection (if any) is using UTF-8.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the files and the HTTP message bodies to verify the encodings?

Comment: Yes, we have.  If we run curl on the two files, one says its iso-8859... and the other utf8.  If we run the perl scripts from the command line, they both come out as utf8.